# kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst and kCGImageAlphaFirst

Tags: objective-c, bitmap, quartz-graphics, pixel, cgcontext

Can you explain to me difference between `kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst` and `kCGImageAlphaFirst`?
 What's mean `Premultiplied` in practice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In short, premultiplied means that the alpha value will also affect the color component values of the pixels when a pixel which is not opaque is represented.

From the Quartz 2D drawing guide:

> For bitmaps that have an alpha component, whether the color components
>   are already multiplied by the alpha value. Premultiplied alpha
>   describes a source color whose components are already multiplied by an
>   alpha value. Premultiplying speeds up the rendering of an image by
>   eliminating an extra multiplication operation per color component. For
>   example, in an RGB color space, rendering an image with premultiplied
>   alpha eliminates three multiplication operations (red times alpha,
>   green times alpha, and blue times alpha) for each pixel in the image.

BTW, Pre-Multiplied is likely what the APIs will force you to use because that is Quartz's preference. Fortunately, the conversions aren't terrible (lossy OTOH…).

---

the shortest way to explain this is in `float` components, using the range `[0...1]`.

If our RGBA input representation is:

```
typedef struct t_rgba { float r,g,b,a; } t_rgba;
const t_rgba rgba = { 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5 };
```

Then to pre-multiply it:

```
t_rgba rgba_PreMul = rgba;
rgba_PreMul.r *= rgba_PreMul.a;
rgba_PreMul.g *= rgba_PreMul.a;
rgba_PreMul.b *= rgba_PreMul.a;
```

Then to de-pre-multiply it:

```
t_rgba rgba_DePreMul = rgba_PreMul;
if (0.0 < rgba_DePreMul.a && 1.0 > rgba_DePreMul.a) {
  const float ialpha = 1.0/rgba_DePreMul.a;
  rgba_DePreMul.r *= ialpha;
  rgba_DePreMul.g *= ialpha;
  rgba_DePreMul.b *= ialpha;
}
```

You might want some saturation in there, too.

Now that's the basic form, which can be repurposed to other numeric representations. Note that these conversions *are lossy*. As well, be careful not to pass premultiplied bitmaps where regular bitmaps are expected, and vice versa.

Comment: I've got pixel [(255/255.0), (100/255.0), (20/255.0),(40/255.0)]. If i understand correctly `premultiplied` means that `red *= (40/255.0)` and so on, but when i use `kCGImageAlphaFirst` then `red = red`?

Comment: @TomaszSzulc yes. and expanded.